# C++ command line input from a text file

Tags: c++

I would like to take numbers from a .txt file and input them through the command line into a program like the example below.  I run the exe using ./program < input.txt. However it prints random numbers. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//print 1st number
cout << argv[1];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cout << argv[1];
```

is equivalent to:

```
char* arg = argv[1];
cout << arg;
```

It just prints the value of the first argument to the program

In your case, you didn't provide an argument to the program.

When you use,

```
./program < input.txt
```

the contents of `input.ext` becomes `stdin` of your program. You can process that using:

```
int c;
while ( (c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF )
{
   fputc(c, stdout);
}
```

If you want to stay with C++ streams, you can use:

```
int c;
while ( (c = cin.get()) != EOF )
{
   cout.put(c);
}
```

Comment: Because `fgetc` and `fputc` are really C++. Yeah, sure, whatever.

Comment: Any idea how I could get the value into a variable instead of printing it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
./program $(cat input.txt)
```

This does the trick.

For example, if input.txt has numbers separated by spaces:

33 1212 1555

Running:

```
./program $(cat input.txt)
```

prints 33 to the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use argv numbers need to be supplied as arguments, i.e.

./program  23 45 67

For ./program < input.txt you need to read from cin (standard input).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int n;
int main()
{
   cin >> n;
   cout << n;
}
```